# Collision of Obj files with mouse and touch events in three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

I was working with my three.js project in which I loads few '.obj ' files in to the scene using 'OBJMTLLoader.js'.

I implemented mouse touch and keyboard events so that I can navigate each objects through the entire scene.

But I need to detect collisions so that when two objects collide, the navigation need to stop in the collided direction. i.e. an object should not get over the other.

I successfully implemented the above for key events by emitting ray to all sides of the object. But the same method doesn't work properly for mouse and touch events.

I also tried to implement 'physi.js', but it seems obj files can't be loaded in 'Physijs.Scene'.

Do anyone know what to be done to implement this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I obtained the solution, using the physi.js itself. I made physijs box mesh of desired sizes and added my obj models to it.I made the meshes visible property to false. And made those meshes to collide. The objects will move along with the meshes.